# How to tell in which version of Ruby a method was first introduced?

Tags: ruby

In the official [Ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org) or elsewhere, is there an easy way of seeing in which version of Ruby a given method was first introduced to the language?

I haven't found such a resource and it seems it would be obviously useful.

Comment: You can checkout https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map where it shows a method's timeline across Ruby versions.

Comment: Keep in mind that apidock.com wasn't updated for years, though.

Comment: Maybe you'll have to write an app that does such a thing:)

Comment: I agree that would be useful information. I'd like to see it in every method's doc, for the Ruby version in which it made its debut and in every subsequent version. For the most part, the doc for a method is updated for a new version by just cutting and pasting the doc for the previous version, so including the birth date would require little or no additional effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try checking out changelogs here https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc but it looks like they skipped few ;)

The only way I can think of is to have all major version binaries, and execute code on them to see if works. If you were looking for `Hash#fetch` you could run `ruby -e 'Hash.new.fetch(0, 0)'` each version which returns 0 will have it implemented, others means some error. You could use `rvm` for that.

You could automatize it with git bisect. But it would have to compile ruby binary for each check, and some dependencies could have changed so I would not expect it to work on first try :D

Answer (score 1):

To complete @Grzegorz answer, you could look for the method you need at [DevDocs](https://devdocs.io/) or [RubyAPI](https://rubyapi.org) and then try to change version (eg.  3.0 -> 2.7, etc.) until the method is not documented.

The only direct method was with [ApiDock](https://apidock.com/ruby) but it's abandoned now and covers only from Ruby 1.8.6 to 2.6.3.

As of today the best (easiest and quickest) method is with DevDocs.

Add all Ruby versions available in DevDocs (2.2 to 3.0).

[image: devdocs - ruby versions]

The search your method and see the lowest match (eg. here with `Regexp#match?`) it's 2.4. If you want to be extra sure you can then check the corresponding ruby [changelog](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/).

[image: devdocs - search]